# Why the address of an array can have a negative value?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-management

I wrote this program which displays the address of a stored array :

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int L[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("L[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &L[i]);
    }
    
    printf("The address of L : %d \n", L);
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed that sometimes the program gives negative address which I did not quite understand.

Why there are negative addresses in memory?
Is this related to the C language?

Comment: When I compile your program using gcc I get a helpful warning about using `%d` - so make sure you're compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: use code blocks , and the code works fine .I will check manually with the terminal..

Comment: "and the code works fine" - no, it does not.

Comment: I think it works with Code Blocks . But Manually (using terminal) u should replace %d with %p

Comment: People who are beginners to lower-level (i.e. _systems_) languages like C, C++, and Rust really should not be using an IDE at all, because it hides a lot of the complexity _that you need to understand and gain experience with_ in order to use the language, toolchain and ecosystem correctly and effectively. _For the sake of your professional development_ **you should uninstall Code Blocks for now** and stick to the terminal environment with command-line tools - only progress on to an IDE after you understand everything that the IDE is hiding from you.

Comment: Ok , I will work more with terminal environment . Thank you for your advice .

Comment: People who are beginners to lower-level (i.e. systems) languages like C, C++, and Rust really should not be using a terminal environment at all because it displays a lot of the complexity that you do not need need to understand.  Most 'beginner' questions on SO are characterised by a total lack of debugging skills/effort, something that an integrated debugger makes much easier.  The user can watch the code stepping and understand what is happening in the memory and stack panes while easily inspecting values etc.  That is much more valuable to beginners than arcane build scripts in text files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why there are negative addresses in memory?

This is an unsupported concern as the output was based on broken code.

---

Do not use a mis-matched specifier `"%d"` to print addresses and incur *undefined behavior* (UB).  `"%d"` is for `int`.  Use `"%p"` with `void *`.  The format of address output is implementation dependent.  I have never come across an implementation that reports negative addresses.

```
printf("The address of L : %p\n", (void *) L);
```

---

You may get an output like

```
The address of L : 0xffffca70
// or 
The address of L : ffff:ca70
// or 
The address of L : Red:70
```

A *pointer* has integer like attributes, but a pointer type is not  certainly reported like an integer.  It is implementation defined.

---

Save time - enable all warnings too.

Comment: Where did you get that UB thing from?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined." C17dr § 7.21.6.1 9.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Also, something about _nasal demons_

Comment: Minor: `printf("The address of L : %p\n", (void *) L);` attempts to print the address of the first element of array `L`.   To print the address of the array (as in the question title): `printf("The address of L : %p\n", (void *) &L);`.  Very likely the same output will be seen.  Yet even if output is different, the pointers are equivalent.

Comment: @dai Re: "something about nasal demons " --> You may think that's funny if your nose/code is runny, but its snot. ;-).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica uhhhh... [banging head on keyboard in pain]